# If $n-1$ is $f(n)$-smooth, $n$ is prime infinitely often. What is the best $f$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If $n-1$ is $f(n)$-[smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number), $n$ is prime infinitely often.  What is the best $f$?

For all primes $p$, $p-1$ is $\frac{p}{2}$-smooth, so $f(n) = \frac{n}{2}$ works.

If $q$ is a Fermat prime, then $q-1$ is $2$-smooth.  Since we cannot prove there are a finite number of Fermat primes it is possible that $f(n) = 2$ works.

Can anything in between be established with certainty?

I considered $f(n) = \sqrt{n}$.  The simplest kind of $\sqrt{n}$-smooth number is a square, and since we don't know if there are an infinite number of primes of the form $k^2+1$ we are in the same situation as with Fermat primes.  I'm not sure how to approach the case when $n-1$ is $\sqrt{n}$-smooth but not square.

I feel like it should be possible to prove this for $f(n)=\frac{n}{\log{n}}$ (there are an infinite number of primes $p$ where $p-1$ is $\frac{p}{\log p}$-smooth).  How can this be shown?  What is the best that is known?

Related:

[Is there any infinite set of primes for which membership can be decided quickly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943964/is-there-any-infinite-set-of-primes-for-which-membership-can-be-decided-quickly)

[Are there infinitely many primes next to smooth numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44163/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-next-to-smooth-numbers?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There has been many works on that problem. [A result of Baker and Harman](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa83/aa8342.pdf) asserts that $p-1$ is $p^{0.2961}$-smooth infinitely often, and seems to be the current published record. It uses very strong results about primes in arithmetic progression. [An earlier result of M. Goldfeld](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6710800&fileId=S0025579300004575) has $f(n)=\sqrt{n}$ using the theorems of Bombieri-Vinogradov and Brun-Titchmarsh.

It's not obvious to me that there should be an easy proof for $f(n)=n/\log n$, since this relates to good estimates for the number of primes of size $\approx x$ in a congruence class to a modulus between $x/\log x$ and $x$.